# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail whith public key authentication

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I'm trying to create a ssh client in java in order to run remote command on an appliance.
With Username/Password authentication I havent' problem, it works fine, but with Public Key Auth it don't works. It returns me: "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)". Autentication whith command ssh in shell works fine so it isn't a key problem.
The dependency that I've installed is: com.jcraft jsch 0.1.55

```
 String remoteShellScript = "vtmenu";

 Session jschSession = null;

 try {

            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            jschSession = jsch.getSession(USERNAME, REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT);
            jsch.addIdentity("/home/ZZZZZZ/.ssh/id_rsa");
            jschSession.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");
            jschSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

            jschSession.connect(SESSION_TIMEOUT);
```

EDIT: (full log)

```
INFO: Connecting to XXXXXX port 22
INFO: Connection established
INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH_0.2.9
INFO: CheckCiphers: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
INFO: CheckKexes: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,curve448-sha512
INFO: curve25519-sha256 is not available.
INFO: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org is not available.
INFO: curve448-sha512 is not available.
DEBUG: kex proposal before removing unavailable algos is: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
DEBUG: kex proposal after removing unavailable algos is: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
INFO: CheckSignatures: ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed448
INFO: ssh-ed25519 is not available.
INFO: ssh-ed448 is not available.
DEBUG: server_host_key proposal before removing unavailable algos is: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa, ssh-dss
DEBUG: server_host_key proposal after removing unavailable algos is: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa, ssh-dss
DEBUG: server_host_key proposal before known_host reordering is: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa, ssh-dss
DEBUG: server_host_key proposal after known_host reordering is: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa, ssh-dss
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO: server proposal: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
INFO: server proposal: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
INFO: server proposal: ciphers c2s: 3des-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO: server proposal: ciphers s2c: 3des-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO: server proposal: MACs c2s: hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com
INFO: server proposal: MACs s2c: hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com
INFO: server proposal: compression c2s: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO: server proposal: compression s2c: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO: server proposal: languages c2s:
INFO: server proposal: languages s2c:
INFO: client proposal: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
INFO: client proposal: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa, ssh-dss
INFO: client proposal: ciphers c2s: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc
INFO: client proposal: ciphers s2c: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc
INFO: client proposal: MACs c2s: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
INFO: client proposal: MACs s2c: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
INFO: client proposal: compression c2s: none
INFO: client proposal: compression s2c: none
INFO: client proposal: languages c2s:
INFO: client proposal: languages s2c:
INFO: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
INFO: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
INFO: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
INFO: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT sent
INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
INFO: ssh_ecdsa_verify: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 signature true
WARN: Permanently added 'XXXXXXX' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_EXT_INFO received
INFO: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
INFO: OpenSSH 7.4 detected: adding rsa-sha2-256 & rsa-sha2-512 to server-sig-algs
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO: Authentications that can continue: publickey
INFO: Next authentication method: publickey
DEBUG: PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms = ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
DEBUG: Signature algorithms unavailable for non-agent identities = [ssh-ed25519, ssh-ed448]
DEBUG: PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms in server-sig-algs = [rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256]
DEBUG: PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms not in server-sig-algs = [ssh-ed25519, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384, ecdsa-sha2-nistp521, ssh-rsa]
DEBUG: rsa-sha2-512 preauth failure
DEBUG: rsa-sha2-256 preauth failure
DEBUG: ssh-rsa preauth failure
INFO: Disconnecting from XXXXXX port 22
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail for methods 'publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive'
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:499)
        at FlashcopyOrchestrator.RunRemoteScript.main(RunRemoteScript.java:44)
```

Comment: It can't be analyzed without the logs given by jsch which you should post here in order to help. Or you just try jsch fork from https://github.com/mwiede/jsch with a java version of 15 and higher... It solves most of the auth problems people have with old jsch version.

Comment: Hi @MatthiasWiedemann, I've tried updating the dependency and now the message is: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail for methods 'publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive'. How can i add more logging?

Comment: Does your key have a passphrase? If so, you should pass it with `addIdentity`

Comment: Use Jsch.setLogger(), either your own implementation of com.jcraft.jsch.Logger, or by using one of the provided loggers (JplLogger, JulLogger, Log4j2Logger or Slf4jLogger).

Comment: Hi @g00se, the private key hasn't got a passphrase

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann here are logs: `DEBUG: PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms = ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
DEBUG: Signature algorithms unavailable for non-agent identities = [ssh-ed25519, ssh-ed448]
DEBUG: PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms in server-sig-algs = [rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256]
DEBUG: PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms not in server-sig-algs = [ssh-ed25519, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384, ecdsa-sha2-nistp521]`

Comment: `DEBUG: rsa-sha2-512 preauth failure
DEBUG: rsa-sha2-256 preauth failure
DEBUG: ssh-rsa cannot be used as public key type for identity /home/XXXXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa
INFO: Disconnecting from XXXXXXX port 22
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail for methods 'publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive'
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:499)
        at FlashcopyOrchestrator.RunRemoteScript.main(RunRemoteScript.java:40)`

Comment: As per readme jsch fork has disabled ssh-rsa by default. To reactivate JSch.setConfig("server_host_key", JSch.getConfig("server_host_key") + ",ssh-rsa") + JSch.setConfig("PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms", JSch.getConfig("PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms") + ",ssh-rsa")

Comment: Hi @MatthiasWiedemann, now with adding your line I've got this error: DEBUG: rsa-sha2-512 preauth failure
DEBUG: rsa-sha2-256 preauth failure
DEBUG: ssh-rsa preauth failure
INFO: Disconnecting from XXXXXXX port 22

Comment: Which java version are u using? Bouncy castle on classpath?

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann the java version is, "java version "11.0.17" 2022-10-18 for IBM i". I've set the classpath as ENVVVAR, the dependdency are all into the jar file

Comment: as per readme, certain algorithms require at least java 15 or bouncycastle on classpath.  Can you please update the question with your full log?

Comment: Hi @MatthiasWiedemann I'ìve uploaded the full log